# How to Clear Cells Based on Blank/Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

With my current code, I'm trying to clear the corresponding cells (columns K:N) when the column (C:J) is blank. It's the reference of Rng. I think it's an `If Then` statement but not sure how to fit it within the code...  I understand this is long but any help would be fantastic!

For example, if C30:J30 is empty it clears K30:N30.  Is it a `If Then` statement with `ClearContents`? Or if C15:J15 is blank then clear K15:N15, etc.

I'm looking for help on clearing cells that are on the same row as the "Active" criteria. But, only after it is copied from "Future Project Hopper" to "CPD-Carryover,Complete&Active". Trying to make sure it's not confusing when I copy/clear C to J and am left with some data in columns K to N. I'm making this for other individuals to use to easily move Active projects from one sheet to another.

```
Const cCrit As Variant = "D"      ' Criteria Column Letter/Number
Const cCols As String = "C:J"     ' Source/Target Data Columns
Const cFRsrc As Long = 15         ' Source First Row

Dim ws1 As Worksheet              ' Source Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet              ' Target Workbook
Dim rng As Range                  ' Filter Range, Copy Range
Dim lRow As Long                  ' Last Row Number
Dim FRtgt As Long                 ' Target First Row
Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult      ' Message Box
Dim Error1 As VbMsgBoxResult      ' Message Box for Errors

' Create references to worksheets.
With ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Future Project Hopper")
    Set ws2 = .Worksheets("CPD-Carryover,Complete&Active")
End With

Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to run the Macro?", vbYesNo, "Run Macro")

If Answer <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

' In Source Worksheet
With ws1
    ' Clear any filters.
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    ' Calculate Last Row.
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cCrit).End(xlUp).row
    ' Calculate Filter Column Range.
    Set rng = .Cells(cFRsrc, cCrit).Resize(lRow - cFRsrc + 1)
    ' Make an offset for the filter to start a row before (above) and
    ' end a row after (below).
    With rng.Offset(-1).Resize(lRow - cFRsrc + 3)
        ' Filter data in Criteria Column.
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Active"
    End With
    ' Create a reference to the Copy Range.
    Set rng = .Columns(cCols).Resize(rng.Rows.Count).Offset(cFRsrc - 1) _
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    ' Clear remaining filters.
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    End With

' Calculate Target First Row.
FRtgt = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, cCrit).End(xlUp).row + 1
' Copy Range and paste to Target Worksheet and clear contents of future project hopper
rng.Copy
ws2.Columns(cCols).Resize(1).Offset(FRtgt - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
rng.Rows.ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a work around by just filtering for blanks and clearing contents verse trying to create an `If Then` for blank rows.

```
Range("D14").Select
    'Re-add filter
    Selection.AutoFilter
    'Fitler for blanks
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$14:$N$34").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="="
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
        'Select Area to be cleared - work around by not clearing based on blank criteria but on filter
        Range("K18:N208").Select
        'Clear potential savings for moved active projects
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("M39").Select
            'Unfilter for blanks
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$14:$N$34").AutoFilter Field:=4
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Future Project Hopper").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
                Clear
        'Filter A-Z
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Future Project Hopper").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
            Add Key:=Range("D14:D34"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Future Project Hopper").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Counts As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Counts = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("C30:J30"))

        If Counts = 0 Then
            .Range("K30:N30").ClearContents
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited new answer:**

I tested your code, and if I understand, your real purpose is to clear columns `C`to `N` on the filtered rows (which are the rows where the cell in column `D` says `"Active"`. You already managed to clear columns `C`to `J`, hence the question.

The solution I propose clears all contents on rows `C`to `N`in one go, no intermediary step needed. Because the rows of interest are already identified, there is no need for a `If... Then`condition.

The cell clearing does happen after the copying operation.

Because I'm not that comfortable with `Resize, Offset`and `Cells`, the proposed solution uses different functions, but should work the same.

Here it is:

```
Const cCrit As Variant = "D"      ' Criteria Column Letter/Number
Const cCols As String = "C:J"     ' Source/Target Data Columns
Const cFRsrc As Long = 15         ' Source First Row
Sub test()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet              ' Source Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet              ' Target Workbook
Dim rng As Range                  ' Filter Range, Copy Range
Dim rngClear As Range             ' Range to be cleared after copy
Dim lRow As Long                  ' Last Row Number
Dim FRtgt As Long                 ' Target First Row
Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult      ' Message Box
Dim Error1 As VbMsgBoxResult      ' Message Box for Errors

' Create references to worksheets.
With ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Feuil1")
    Set ws2 = .Worksheets("Feuil2")
End With

Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to run the Macro?", vbYesNo, "Run Macro")

If Answer <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

' In Source Worksheet
With ws1
    ' Clear any filters.
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    ' Calculate Last Row.
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cCrit).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Calculate Filter Column Range.
    Set rng = .Cells(cFRsrc, cCrit).Resize(lRow - cFRsrc + 1)
    ' Make an offset for the filter to start a row before (above) and
    ' end a row after (below).
    With rng.Offset(-1).Resize(lRow - cFRsrc + 3)
        ' Filter data in Criteria Column.
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Active"
    End With
    ' Create a reference to the Copy Range.
    Set rng = .Columns(cCols).Resize(rng.Rows.Count).Offset(cFRsrc - 1) _
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'Set here the range to be cleared after the copy. Same rows as rng, but with extended columns (C to N)
    Set rngClear = .Range("C" & cFRsrc & ":" & "N" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    ' Clear remaining filters.
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

' Calculate Target First Row.
FRtgt = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, cCrit).End(xlUp).Row + 1
' Copy Range and paste to Target Worksheet and clear contents of future project hopper
rng.Copy
ws2.Columns(cCols).Resize(1).Offset(FRtgt - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Clears columns C to N in ws1 for copied rows
rngClear.ClearContents

End Sub
```

You could improve this code further by using variables for `"C","N"`.

**Old answer:**

A bit of code that may help :

```
If IsEmpty(Range("C30:D30")) Then
    Range("K30:N30").ClearContents
Endif
```

From there, you have to loop on the given range (you can probably reuse `lrow` or `rng.Rows.Count` for that).

From what I understand from the code, it takes a range of data in a sheet ("Future Project Hopper"), filters it and copies it in sheet "CPD-Carryover,Complete&Active".
If you want to clear the latter, your additional code must be placed at the end, before or after `rng.Rows.ClearContents`.

Comment: Would this need to be defined like `Rng`? So, that it loops and continues down the columns until it reaches the last filled cell?

Comment: I guess you could define a `rng2` and look on it but I'm not using this kind of method in my own macros. I would just loop from the first inserted line (`FRtgt` I think) to the last one (should be `FRtgt+rng.Rows.Count-1`). Have you tried the if/then condition?

Comment: I did try your code above but it didn't clear the contents and I also tried:
`If IsEmpty(Rng) Then
Worksheets("Future Project Hopper").Range("C15:J15" & Rows.Column).End(xlUp).ClearContents
End If`

This didn't work either.  I placed it right before the `application.cutcopymode = false`

Comment: I think I misunderstood your purpose. Please read the updated answer and tell me if it helps you.

Comment: I'll restate and change my original question but I'm looking for help on clearing cells that are on the same row as the "Active" criteria. But, only after it is copied from "Future Project Hopper" to "CPD-Carryover,Complete&Active".  Trying to make sure it's not confusing when I copy/clear `C` to `J` and am left with some data in columns `K` to `N`.  I'm making this for other individuals to use to easily move Active projects from one sheet to another.

Comment: The final result should be : active projects are copied to the second sheet, rows `C` to `J` and `K` to `N` are cleared. Is that right ? If it is, please try the updated code and tell me if it reaches your goal or not. If it isn't, what is your desired outcome ?